# Adding new members to whatsapp group while admin lost his whatsapp phone number

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger

I am part of a whatsapp group in which there is only one admin. Unfortunately the admin is not using the number he used for whatsapp. Now how can we add a new user? Or how can someone else become the admin.? And we don't know the invite link for the group also.